# Issues with constant expression

Tags: c++

I have some issues in compiling a code. I have this particular code

```
    typedef double Type;

    static const Type MAX_VALUE = __DBL_MAX__;
    static const Type MIN_VALUE = -__DBL_MAX__;
```

Now when I try to compile it. It shows the following error

```
error: a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

I change the definition const to constexpr. But it shows the following error

```
error: ‘constexpr’ does not name a type
note: C++0x ‘constexpr’ only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I get no such error.  Are you absolutely sure that these lines are the ones causing the error?  http://ideone.com/ZtPPU

Comment: Yeah, I get that error. It shows the same file and the line number as I mentioned in the code. Could there be any other issues?

Comment: "note: C++0x ‘constexpr’ only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x" You need to supply the `-std=c++0x` flag to the compiler.

Comment: This is fine with GCC 4.7.0. @rajansthapit, Which compiler are you using, and does this combined with an empty `main` compile? It sounds more like you're taking this from a larger project where something else might actually be the issue.

Comment: @rajansthapit But *which* line?  You have given us four lines of code and haven't indicated which one triggers the error.

Comment: -std=c++0x flag fixed the issue. Thanks KennyTm

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball tells me these lines are inside a class definition.  That's a very important piece of information you left out.

Prior to C++11, only integral and enumerated static members could be initialized inside the class body.  Others, including floating-point, must be defined outside.

Comment: It's a good thought, but isn't there another error for this? I recall GCC explicitly saying it has to be integral.

Comment: @Ben yeah the lines are inside a class definition